# Using DisplayTag library, I want to have the currently selected row have a unique custom class using the TableDecorator

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, displaytag

I have been trying to figure out how to highlight the selected row in a table. In my jsp I have jsp scriplet that can get access to the id of the row the displaytag library is creating.  I want to compare it to the the id of the current row selected by the user ${currentNoteId}.  Right now if the row id = 849 (hardcoded) the class "currentClass" is added to just that row of the table.  I need to change the 849 for the {$currentNoteId} and I don't know how to do it.  I am using java, Spring MVC.  The jsp:
...

```
<%
request.setAttribute("dyndecorator", new org.displaytag.decorator.TableDecorator()  
{  
   public String addRowClass()  
   {  
      edu.ilstu.ais.advisorApps.business.Note row =               
      (edu.ilstu.ais.advisorApps.business.Note)getCurrentRowObject();      
            String rowId = row.getId();
            if ( rowId.equals("849") ) {
                return "currentClass";
            }
            return null;              
        }
    });
%> 

<c:set var="currentNoteId" value="${studentNotes.currentNote.id}"/>
...
<display:table id="noteTable" name="${ studentNotes.studentList }" pagesize="20"
  requestURI="notesView.form.html" decorator="dyndecorator">
    <display:column title="Select" class="yui-button-match" href="/notesView.form.html"
      paramId="note.id" paramProperty="id">
      <input type="button" class="yui-button-match2" name="select" value="Select"/>
    </display:column>
    <display:column property="userName" title="Created By" sortable="true"/>
    <display:column property="createDate" title="Created On" sortable="true" 
       format="{0,date,MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a}"/>
    <display:column property="detail" title="Detail" sortable="true"/>
</display:table>
...
```

This could also get done using javascript and that might be best, but the documentation suggested this so I thought I would try it.  I cannot find an example anywhere using the addRowClass() unless the comparison is to a field already in the row (a dollar amount is used in the documentation example) or hardcoded in like the "849" id.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and did it in javascript instead.  When I used the currentNoteId in the scriptlet like this:

```
String rowId = row.getId();
String noteId = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("currentNoteId");
if ( rowId.equals( noteId ) ) {
    return "currentClass";
}
return null;
```

I received the error:  got error  Cannot refer to a non-final variable pageContext inside an inner class defined in a different method.

So instead I wrote:

```
function highlightCurrentTableRow(tableId, currentRowId ) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    console.log( "rowId", "'" + currentRowId + "'" );
    for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        rowId = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
        console.log( "  rowId", "'" + rowId + "'" );
        if ( rowId == currentRowId ) {
            console.log( "got here" );
            var rowClass = rows[i].getAttribute("class");
            rows[i].setAttribute("class", rowClass + " currentClass"   );  
        };
    }
}
```

Actually this may not work in IE because of "class" is a key word so I used Yahoo YUI addClass(element, class) instead so I replaced

```
var rowClass = rows[i].getAttribute("class");
rows[i].setAttribute("class", rowClass + " currentClass"   );
```

with

```
YAHOO.util.Dom.addClass(rows[i],'currentClass');
```